# Dynamic Text on Image Suddenly Not Working

Tags: php, image, text, xampp

So I'm creating a site that returns quotes based on an input. I want the quotes to be returned as text on a picture, so I found a guide at http://jonlim.ca/2011/11/creating-an-image-with-dynamic-text-in-php/ to help me.

I'm running xampp to test my php and the code currently looks like...

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
/*$string = $_GET['days'];*/
$im = imagecreatefrompng("twainpen.png");
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagepng($im);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'daniel.ttf';

$initialX = '153';
$initialY = '35';
$increaseY = '23';

$fontSize = '16';
$fontRotation = '0';

$firstline = 'What do you mean';
$secondline = 'there are ' . $string . ' days until';
$thirdline = 'Christmas?! What am';
$fourthline = 'I supposed to do until';
$fifthline = 'then? WAIT?! I am';
$sixthline = 'not a patient man!';

//imagestring($im, $font, $px, 20, $string, $black);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY, $black,         $font, $firstline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+$increaseY,  $black, $font, $secondline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*2), $black, $font, $thirdline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*3), $black, $font, $fourthline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*4), $black, $font, $fifthline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*5), $black, $font, $sixthline);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This code is nearly identical to the guide and the really frustrating thing is when I was last working on this a few weeks ago I got it to work, but after I started futzing around with something else I came back and it wouldn't work anymore (all that happens is the picture shows up without any text on it). I'm betting the solution is some dumb mistake I'm making, but not sure what it is. The font is in the same folder as the code as well as the picture.

Any help or thoughts that can be given are appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to remove line 8 . it outputs the image before adding the text. then set the path to the font properly . 
Described Here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['days'];
$im = imagecreatefrompng("twainpen.png");
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$font = './daniel.ttf';

$initialX = '153';
$initialY = '35';
$increaseY = '23';

$fontSize = '16';
$fontRotation = '0';

$firstline = 'What do you mean';
$secondline = 'there are ' . $string . ' days until';
$thirdline = 'Christmas?! What am';
$fourthline = 'I supposed to do until';
$fifthline = 'then? WAIT?! I am';
$sixthline = 'not a patient man!';

//imagestring($im, $font, $px, 20, $string, $black);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY, $black,         $font, $firstline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+$increaseY,  $black, $font, $secondline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*2), $black, $font, $thirdline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*3), $black, $font, $fourthline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*4), $black, $font, $fifthline);
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $fontRotation, $initialX, $initialY+($increaseY*5), $black, $font, $sixthline);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: I did as you said and now it just seems to return a placeholder thumbnail for image not found. I also tried adding the '/' in front of the twainpen.png to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure ? you have to add './' not '/' .

Comment: header("Content-Type: image/png");
    /*$string = $_GET['days'];*/
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("twainpen.png");
    imagealphablending($im, false);
    imagesavealpha($im,true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $font = './daniel.ttf';

Answer (score 0):

Payam Mohammadi fixed my problem with the simple solution of: "add this before header: error_reporting(0);"

The imagepng($im); line had to be taken out as well.